# Why surge show page not found if we the file name is not index.html?

Tags: html, surge.sh

Suppose you have an HTML file named abc.html. If you deploy this to surge, it will be deployed but page not found error will be displayed. If you rename it to index.html and re deploy, the page is displayed. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that if you go to `youURL.surge.sh/abc.html` it will display fine.

Looks like surge servers are complying to the defaults of the web by serving an `index.html` when one is present.